# How to convert LoadRunner scripts to JMeter compatible scripts with least re-work effort?

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner

We have few existing scripts in LoadRunner. Is there a way to convert those scripts to JMeter scripts(JMX files), which requires a little to no amount of re-work(correlation, parameterization, etc)?

If it is not that straight-forward, could you please suggest the optimal way for shifting to Jmeter from LoadRunner?

Comment: "which requires a little to no amount of re-work(correlation, parameterization, etc)?"  You mean, "Magic!"

Answer (score 4):

This tool was released lately.

If you upload a ZIP of your LoadRunner script, it will convert it to JMeter or Selenium.
It might not be 100%, but it will tell you what it couldn't convert and save you a lot of troubles.

[shiftleft.blazemeter.com](https://shiftleft.blazemeter.com)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The fastest and the easiest way is just recording them.

1. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Configure VuGen to use JMeter as a proxy

   [image: LoadRunner JMeter Proxy]
3. Run your test with 1 virtual user and 1 iteration. While your test is running JMeter will create the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers
4. When execution is finished you will have JMeter script "skeleton"

See [How to Convert LoadRunner Tests to JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-loadrunner-tests-jmeter) article for detailed explanation of above steps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the above process is the most practical and reliable way. But I found an open source project which says it converts LR scripts to JMeter. Found it here: http://www.findbestopensource.com/product/lr2jm But there is no documentation or manual for using it. Also the URL given for SVN Checkout isn't working. Does anybody have any idea on this project?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my project to convert loadrunner http/html scripts to jmeter.

https://github.com/ShravanAkula/LR_Jmeter_Converter.

we are working to reduce the manual effort involved in converting the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is recording them with [Loadium Record & Play](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/loadium-extension/eecaejegccegjjjngokgelmehfkmpico?hl=tr&authuser=0)

[image]

Also after recording you can change any collection you want. It provides donwloading the scripts or running with Loadium. We used it. Also for the complex scripts we took support from Loadium Tech Team. They wrote our scripts less than one week.